# Struts2 Sitemesh not working in WAS 6 server

Tags: struts2, decorator, sitemesh

I have a struts2-spring application which works fine in jetty server but when i try migrating it to WAS 6 the decorator(sitemesh) is not getting applied. The server logs shows no error.Is this a known issue ?
my web.xml looks like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the url-pattern, websphere internally  use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` for something, the solution is to change that for something new like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and put application files below that path